# how can I find the path of virtualenv python

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

how can I find the path of virtualenv python ,built with this tutorial?
(i want to find python in this env and use it in my eclipse)

```
$ sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
$ export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
$ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

$ echo -e "\n# virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh" >> ~/.bashrc

$ source ~/.bashrc

$ mkvirtualenv cv -p python3
```

Comment: Activate the created env first: `workon cv`. Then issue `which python`, this will show you the path to the executable. Also, when an env is activated, issuing `echo $VIRTUAL_ENV` will show you the path to the directory containing env files.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `which` to find out which binary will be executed...

For example:

```
$ which python3
/home/attie/projects/thing/venv/bin/python3
```

By default it just shows the first match, but you can give the `-a` argument to show all:

```
$ which -a python3
/home/attie/projects/thing/venv/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: On Windows, using cmd `where python` works.

Answer (score 6):

There is VIRTUAL_ENV system variable already set with the path.

Check <your_venv>/bin/activate (which is a simple script) to see how the virtual env is setup in general, but this variable will give you the clean path already:

```
echo $VIRTUAL_ENV
<full virtual env path>
```

Answer (score 3):

`mkvirtualenv` creates virtualenvs in `$WORKON_HOME`, that is your virtualenv is in `$HOME/.virtualenvs/cv/`.