# Loading a virtualenv in a job file to run on linux cluster

Tags: python, linux, bash, virtualenv, cluster-computing

I'm trying to set up a job file to run on a linux cluster using

```
$ qsub network.job
```

I have loaded the module needed to execute the script, however a also need to activate a virtual environment that comes with the module.

```sh
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -cwd
#$ -j y
#$ -o output/
echo "Running job script"

module load python/python3

./network.py 
echo "Finished job script"
```

Including

```
$source activate machinelearning
```

does not activate the virtualenv

What do I need to add to the file to activate the virtualenv machine learning that comes when loading the module python/python3?

Comment: I suspect you'll need to create a custom Python module containing all of your dependencies, then load it, e.g. with something like `module load my_custom/python`. I've also seen the use of a bash script that modifies `PYTHONPATH` directly.

Comment: I suspect your `source` line in your script is incorrect.  How did you create the virtual environment that you intend to use, and how is it being distributed to your cluster nodes?

Comment: I didn't create the virtual environment, it is part of the loaded module, and I can't seem to find the path to where it is located. Before I was only using the cluster on an interactive session, so all I had to do was ```Module Load python/python3``` and then ```source activate machinelearning```

Comment: "I didn't create the virtual environment, it is part of the loaded module"—that's not how virtual environments work.

Answer (score 0):

```
source /PATH/WHERE/YOUR/VIRTUAL/ENVIRONMENT/EXISTS/bin/activate
```

for example in the subdirectory venv of your homedir

```
source ~/venv/machinelearning/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your comment response, the `source` command may not be the problem.  The typical approach in python virtual environments is to call `source` on the `activate` script inside the virtual environment.  For more information on `source`, see [this](https://superuser.com/a/46146) superuser post.

In this case, since the command `source activate machinelearning` works for you in an interactive session, it's likely that there's a script called `activate` in your home directory (or whichever directory you were working from) that takes `machinelearning` as an argument, and activates the appropriate virtual environment.

Here's my best stab at solving your immediate problem:

Since you are able to activate the virtual environment in an interactive session, log in to an interactive session and activate the virtual environment.  Once you have done so, type `which python3` in your terminal, and [it should give you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51750686/487056) the full path to the virtual environment you're working in.  Take that full path and replace the last `python3` with `activate`, and that is the script you should source.  For example:

```
$>which python3
/home/cmf05/environments/machinelearning/bin/python3
```

Then place this in your script between `module load python/python3` and `./network.py`:

```
source /home/cmf05/environments/machinelearning/bin/activate
```

As an aside: `module load` isn't something that's built in to any systems I've ever worked on, but it looks like you're submitting a job to a cluster that's managed by slurm or similar.  It seems like this is loading all of the specific files you need for your compute job.  I would recommend tagging the question with your specific cluster computing environment and putting that in the title for more focused help, in case this doesn't solve your issue.